# Template function in C++ with any number of argments

Tags: c++, function, templates, arguments

I'm trying to write a template function with lots of arguments so I only have to use as many as I need. I wanted to do it the simple way since I am a novice programmer. My code for the function is:

```
template<typename T1 = NULL, typename T2 = NULL> 
void showMessage(T1 input1 = NULL, T2 input2 = NULL) { cout << to_str(input1) << to_str(input2) << endl; }
```

And I wanted to call it like:

```
showMessage("Hello");
```

or

```
showMessage("Hello ","World");
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

I don't want to default the inputs to " " because they might be a number or bool etc. So I used NULL instead.

Normally this kind of thing works with functions, so I thought it might work with templates too. :(

Comment: Please explain "But it doesn't seem to work..." How did your program behave?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variadic template to accept any number of arguments.

```
void showMessage()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void showMessage(T const& first, Args&&... rest)
{
    std::cout << first;
    showMessage(std::forward<Args>(rest)...);
}
```

Here's something a little simpler that will also work in C++03 (but it will only accept a limited number of arguments, and it requires them to be default constructible)

```
template<typename T = std::string,
         typename U = std::string,
         typename V = std::string>
void showMessage(T const& t = T(), U const& u = U(), V const& v = V())
{
    std::cout << t << u << v << std::endl;
}
```

The reason I use `std::string` here as the default type is because a default constructed one will print nothing when sent to `cout`. You could make your own special type for this purpose:

```
struct Nothing {};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Nothing) { return os; }
```

Answer (score -1):

In C, the implementation of printf() provides an example of how to accomplish this using the va_list, macros included in 'stdarg.h'.

https://benlearn.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/variable-length-parameter-listing-cc/

Answer (score -2):

If you want your function to have any number of arguments (but at least one), you can use `<stdarg>`. Function declaration syntax:

```
void showMessage(int nArguments,...);
```

The first argument must tell you how many arguments will follow, either by simply putting there a number or by any other method (look up `printf()`).

To read the arguments you will need to use `va_list`, `va_start()`, `va_arg()` and `va_end()`.

Comment: Would be nice to know what I received the -1s for, just saying.